# Finding a homomorphism

Tags: discrete-mathematics, abstract-algebra

I'm not sure if I'm solving this problem correctly. Can someone verify?

> ***Question***: Find a non-trivial homomorphism from  $[\mathbb{Z}_6, \oplus_6]$ to $[\mathbb{Z}_9, \oplus_9]$

---

***My solution attempt ***

> $f(0)=1, \quad f(1)=4,\quad f(2)=7,\quad f(3)=1,\quad f(4)=4, \quad f(5)=7$

I came up with the above solution by looking at the generators for $\mathbb{Z}_6$ and $\mathbb{Z}_9$. One of $\mathbb{Z}_9$'s generators is $4$ and one of $\mathbb{Z}_7$'s generators is $1$.Thus, I created a mapping $1 \rightarrow 4$.

Is this a valid solution? If not, where did I go wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You can never have $f(0) = 1$  for a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

As Robert pointed out, the identity must remain the identity under a group homormorphism. Now it's easy to find a homomorphism from $\mathbb{Z}/6\mathbb{Z}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$. And it's also easy to embed $\mathbb{Z}/3\mathbb{Z}$ into $\mathbb{Z}/9\mathbb{Z}$ by multiplying by 3.

Comment: I understand how to find a homomorphism from Z6 to Z3. It's cyclic, right? f(0)=0, f(1)=1, f(2)=2, f(3)=0, f(4)=1, f(5)=2 Then we map that homomorphism to Z9?

Comment: @maths_student15: Then what do you not understand?

Comment: I hit the enter button by mistake as I was typing. :-) See edit

Comment: @maths_student15: Ah. Yup correct. =) I should say that we don't map the homomorphism but we compose that homomorphism with the next one that embeds Z/3Z into Z/9Z.

Comment: Okay. By "compose", you mean this? -> g(0)=0, g(1)=3, and g(2) = 6? Then we can use f(g(x)), a composition, to map Z6 to Z9. Is that right?

Comment: @maths_student15: You got your $f,g$ in the wrong order. The final isomorphism you want is $g \circ f$ or $x \mapsto g(f(x))$.